# Two joins and two count getting laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables in example. users, grammar_learned, words_learned

First:

```
CREATE TABLE grammar_learned
(
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    grammar_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE words_learned
(
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  word_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE users
(
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);
```

And my query:

```
$users = User::leftJoin('words_learned', 'users.id', '=', 'words_learned.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('grammar_learned', 'users.id', '=', 'grammar_learned.user_id')
            ->selectRaw('users.*, count(words_learned.id) as learned_count, count(grammar_learned.id) as grammar_count')
            ->groupBy('users.id')->orderBy("learned_count", "desc")->get();
```

I have 1 row in my table grammar_learned and 3 row in words_learned table, but query returns 3 row (count) for **words_learned** - properly and 3 rows for **grammar_learned** (must returns 1). I don't understand why, please help

Shortly: 
I want this result:

```
 0 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "username"
    "learned_count" => 3
    "grammar_count" => 1
  ]
```

But I get

```
0 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "username"
    "learned_count" => 3
    "grammar_count" => 3
  ]
```

Comment: When you join multiple tables together, you are going to end up pulling at least the number of rows that match your criteria on `words_learned`. Could you include a sample of what your returned dataset currently looks like, and also what you actually want it to look like in your question above? That will make it easier for us to figure out exactly what you are wanting. The solution may be either using sub-queries, or possibly a case statement in your select list columns.

Comment: @gmiley thx, have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try the following. I removed your joins and used subqueries instead...

```php
$selectString = 'users.*, (select count(1) from words_learned wl where wl.user_id = users.id) as learned_count, ';
$selectString = $selectString . '(select count(1) from grammar_learned gl where gl.user_id = users.id) as grammar_count ';
$users = User::selectRaw($selectString)->groupBy('users.id')->orderBy("learned_count", "desc")->get();
```

Here is what it comes out to as straight SQL. You had the following:

```sql
select u.*, count(wl.id) as word_cnt, 
       count(gl.if) as grammar_cnt
from Users u
join words_learned wl
on wl.user_id = u.id
join grammar_learned gl
on gl.user_id = u.id
group by u.id
order by word_cnt desc;
```

Which I basically changed to this:

```sql
select u.*, 
      (select count(1) from words_learned wl where wl.user_id = u.id) as word_count,
      (select count(1) from grammar_learned gl where gl.user_id = u.id) as grammar_count
from users u
group by u.id
order by word_count desc;
```